# Related to order statistics in probability theory

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If $x$ and $y$ are two independently and identically distributed random variables then can we write the following?

$$P(x<c)+P((x-c)y<C_1,x>c)=P(x<c,x>y)+P((x-c)y<C_1,x>c,x>y)+P(x<c,x<y)+P((x-c)y<C_1,x>c,x<y)$$
where $c>0, C_1>0$.
If we can write then please provide the detailed steps.

Any help in this regard will be much appreciated.

BR

Frank

Comment: Words such as *question* do not add information to titles. Please [edit] the title so that it better describes the specifics of your question. Do not hesitate to make it longer or include a formula if needed. More tips [here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959). *(autocomment)*

Comment: I have changed the question according to your advice @normal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any event $E, F$, we have the law of total probability:
$$ P(E) = P(E\cap F) + P(E\cap F^c) $$
So if $\Pr\{Y = X\}$ is zero (e.g. continuous random variable), then your results hold, as in that case
$$ \Pr\{Y < X\} + \Pr\{Y > X\} = 1$$

Comment: Excellent Help. Thanks a lot @BGM